# Qt C++: How to change layout after new project opening?

Tags: c++, qt, layout, user-interface, qt-designer

I would like to create two layouts for my program. The first one would be showed to user after startup of program and would contains two push buttons - new/open project and the right side for recent projects. The second would be for entering the data and should be opened in the same window as first layout.  Because I'm new to Qt, I don't know how to solve this problem - can be solved with code or Qt Creator's designer (.ui files)? Please provide an example, because I don't have any really experiance yet.

The second thing which I need to solve is to save recent projects, so the program can recognize them after it's closed. How to do that?

Comment: I don't have any experience with the designer, but I've done this in code using QStackedWidget.

Comment: Can you please provide some example how to add other widgets on this widget and how to change between them. I have another question - If I don't want to use Qt Creator's designer, then I uncheck "Generate form" while I'm creating new project?

Comment: @user1257255 Yes, you uncheck that option if you don't want to use Qt Designer.

Comment: @user125755 Just look at [the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstackedwidget.html), everything is there, including sample code. You just use `setCurrentIndex` or `setCurrentWidget` to switch from one widget to another.

Comment: Thanks, this solution solved my problem. Please answer on this question, so I can accept your solution as right.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. The approach I would take is to create a QMainWindow and two widgets, each one containing the layout I want. I'd then set the widget I want to show as the main window's central widget with QMainWindow::setCentralWidget(). Make sure to hide() and show() the widgets as needed. You can also delete the first widget if you no longer need it.

For saving the list of projects, you can use QSettings.

Comment: Is this possible to do by Qt Creator's designer, so I wouldn't have to code all this?

Comment: @user1257255 Designer is for designing. It can't write your application for you. Qt is a C++ framework, not a "click&play" system.

Comment: Ok. But it's possible to create two layouts and then just change them when this is needed?

Comment: @user1257255 Yes. That's what the Designer is there for. You design your widgets in it as you want them, and then create instances of them in your code and display them wherever you want. In this case, you would put them in a QMainWindow (using setCentralWidget) or inside another QWidget; whatever suits you better.

Comment: Is it possible to hide (as layers in image editing programs) first parent widget, including all subwidgets and then create new (second) parent widget, which would be used for other actions then first? If there is any way to do that, please attach some example.

Comment: @user1257255 If you hide a widget, all its child widgets are hidden automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at a few tutorials on youtube, which I found to be very helpful as it's amazingly straight forward when demonstrated visually.

e.g.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2edb0VOkx-k

Comment: I've already watched a lot of these videos, but there is not solution for my problem.